# MongooseJS: Getting records using array elements as query and using callbacks not working

Tags: mongoose

I have an array of zip codes likes this:

```
zipCodes = [1234, 5678, 1357, 2468];
```

Now, I need to fetch the locations based on these zip codes. I am doing it as follows:

```
locations = [];
zipCodes.forEach(function(zip) {
    Addresses.findOne({ zipCode: zip }, function(error, address) {
        //assuming it is a success
        locations.push(address);
    }
});

//data which works on locations
```

Problem is that the data (in the end) which works on locations does not have all the addresses - at least when it is being accessed. If I delay by 5 - 10 seconds (using setTimeOut after zipCodes.forEach()), then locations contains all the addresses.
What I suspect is the cause is that the `push()` into locations happens asynchronously and not in time when locations is accessed in the end.
How do I ensure that all the addresses are filled in locations before I can access it without using setTimeOut()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct; the `findOne` callbacks occur asynchronously so you have to wait until they're completed before processing `locations`.

One way to handle this is with a flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```js
locations = [];
async.each(zipCodes, function(zip, callback) {
  Addresses.findOne({ zipCode: zip }, function(error, address) {
    //assuming it is a success
    locations.push(address);
    callback();
  });
}, function (err) {
  //data which works on locations 
});
```

Comment: Is the `function(err)` which will contain the code that will work on locations called once or as many times as there are elements in the array? Basically, I intend to return the locations data to the caller of the function containing the above code. So, I intend to return once and with all the locations - will this work here?

Comment: @user2104976 The `function(err)` callback that's the third parameter to `async.each` is called once when all the `async.each` functions have called their callback (which is what you want).

Comment: Oh! So the callback() and function(err) are two different functions? I was assuming that callback() will call function(err). I am confused since the documentation here https://github.com/caolan/async#each uses the same name for both the functions...

Comment: @user2104976 Right, they're separate functions.  `callback` is a function that's internal to `async` that it uses to keep track of when each iteration has completed.

Comment: What I understood is that `callback()` need not be defined. Is my understanding correct? Or should I define the callback() function?